# Ajax error ó Request-URI Too Large

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables, http

**1 .Problema al visualizar la tabla.**

[image: Al recargar la pagina para ver la tabla, muestra este mensaje]
Al dar OK, me aparece la tabla pero sin ningún registro. (Obviamente tengo registros).

**2. No se visualiza la tabla (tengo registros en mi BD)**

[image: Tabla vacía]

**3. Al ver las opciones de desarrollador en Google Chrome igual encontre este error.**

[image: Erro en el Developer Tools - Google Chrome]

**4. Guardar funciona bien. Tanto BD como Formulario.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descripción técnica.

1. Estoy usando Laravel con Laraadmin.
2. Este problema lo tengo solo al crear una tabla con 40 columnas (nunca había hecho una tabla tan larga).
3. Puedo crear tablas con menos columnas y sin ningún problema.
4. Puedo guardar mis registros sin ningun problema.
5. Problema principal, visualizar la tabla.

**Controlador**.

```js
<?php
/**
 * Controller genrated using LaraAdmin
 * Help: http://laraadmin.com
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers\LA;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Validator;
use Datatables;
use Collective\Html\FormFacade as Form;
use Dwij\Laraadmin\Models\Module;
use Dwij\Laraadmin\Models\ModuleFields;

use App\Models\Empleado;

class EmpleadosController extends Controller
{
 public $show_action = true;
 public $view_col = 'apellidos';
 public $listing_cols = ['id', 'apellido_paterno', 'apellido_materno', 'nombre', 'empresa', 'departamento', 'puesto', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'direccion', 'ciudad', 'sexo', 'curp', 'rfc', 'nss', 'correo', 'contrato_adicional', 'infonavit', 'banco', 'cuenta', 'tarjeta', 'clave_interbancaria', 'fecha_ingreso', 'contrato', 'renovacion_contrato', 'reglamento_interno', 'aviso_privacidad', 'cyc', 'horario_lunes', 'horario_martes', 'horario_miercoles', 'horario_jueves', 'horario_viernes', 'horario_sabado', 'horario_domingo', 'renuncia', 'finiquito', 'convenio', 'baja_imss'];
 
 public function __construct() {
  // Field Access of Listing Columns
  if(\Dwij\Laraadmin\Helpers\LAHelper::laravel_ver() == 5.3) {
   $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    $this->listing_cols = ModuleFields::listingColumnAccessScan('Empleados', $this->listing_cols);
    return $next($request);
   });
  } else {
   $this->listing_cols = ModuleFields::listingColumnAccessScan('Empleados', $this->listing_cols);
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * Display a listing of the Empleados.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function index()
 {
  $module = Module::get('Empleados');
  
  if(Module::hasAccess($module->id)) {
   return View('la.empleados.index', [
    'show_actions' => $this->show_action,
    'listing_cols' => $this->listing_cols,
    'module' => $module
   ]);
  } else {
            return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
        }
 }

 /**
  * Show the form for creating a new empleado.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function create()
 {
  //
 }

 /**
  * Store a newly created empleado in database.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "create")) {
  
   $rules = Module::validateRules("Empleados", $request);
   
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
   
   if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
   }
   
   $insert_id = Module::insert("Empleados", $request);
   
   return redirect()->route(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.empleados.index');
   
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Display the specified empleado.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function show($id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "view")) {
   
   $empleado = Empleado::find($id);
   if(isset($empleado->id)) {
    $module = Module::get('Empleados');
    $module->row = $empleado;
    
    return view('la.empleados.show', [
     'module' => $module,
     'view_col' => $this->view_col,
     'no_header' => true,
     'no_padding' => "no-padding"
    ])->with('empleado', $empleado);
   } else {
    return view('errors.404', [
     'record_id' => $id,
     'record_name' => ucfirst("empleado"),
    ]);
   }
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Show the form for editing the specified empleado.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function edit($id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "edit")) {   
   $empleado = Empleado::find($id);
   if(isset($empleado->id)) { 
    $module = Module::get('Empleados');
    
    $module->row = $empleado;
    
    return view('la.empleados.edit', [
     'module' => $module,
     'view_col' => $this->view_col,
    ])->with('empleado', $empleado);
   } else {
    return view('errors.404', [
     'record_id' => $id,
     'record_name' => ucfirst("empleado"),
    ]);
   }
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Update the specified empleado in storage.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "edit")) {
   
   $rules = Module::validateRules("Empleados", $request, true);
   
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
   
   if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();;
   }
   
   $insert_id = Module::updateRow("Empleados", $request, $id);
   
   return redirect()->route(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.empleados.index');
   
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Remove the specified empleado from storage.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
 public function destroy($id)
 {
  if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "delete")) {
   Empleado::find($id)->delete();
   
   // Redirecting to index() method
   return redirect()->route(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.empleados.index');
  } else {
   return redirect(config('laraadmin.adminRoute')."/");
  }
 }
 
 /**
  * Datatable Ajax fetch
  *
  * @return
  */
 public function dtajax()
 {
  $values = DB::table('empleados')->select($this->listing_cols)->whereNull('deleted_at');
  $out = Datatables::of($values)->make();
  $data = $out->getData();

  $fields_popup = ModuleFields::getModuleFields('Empleados');
  
  for($i=0; $i < count($data->data); $i++) {
   for ($j=0; $j < count($this->listing_cols); $j++) { 
    $col = $this->listing_cols[$j];
    if($fields_popup[$col] != null && starts_with($fields_popup[$col]->popup_vals, "@")) {
     $data->data[$i][$j] = ModuleFields::getFieldValue($fields_popup[$col], $data->data[$i][$j]);
    }
    if($col == $this->view_col) {
     $data->data[$i][$j] = '<a href="'.url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/empleados/'.$data->data[$i][0]).'">'.$data->data[$i][$j].'</a>';
    }
    // else if($col == "author") {
    //    $data->data[$i][$j];
    // }
   }
   
   if($this->show_action) {
    $output = '';
    if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "edit")) {
     $output .= '<a href="'.url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/empleados/'.$data->data[$i][0].'/edit').'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" style="display:inline;padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
    }
    
    if(Module::hasAccess("Empleados", "delete")) {
     $output .= Form::open(['route' => [config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '.empleados.destroy', $data->data[$i][0]], 'method' => 'delete', 'style'=>'display:inline']);
     $output .= ' <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
     $output .= Form::close();
    }
    $data->data[$i][] = (string)$output;
   }
  }
  $out->setData($data);
  return $out;
 }
}
```

```html
**Tabla**

@extends("la.layouts.app")

@section("contentheader_title", "Empleados")
@section("contentheader_description", "Empleados listing")
@section("section", "Empleados")
@section("sub_section", "Listing")
@section("htmlheader_title", "Empleados Listing")

@section("headerElems")
@la_access("Empleados", "create")
 <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddModal">Add Empleado</button>
@endla_access
@endsection

@section("main-content")

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<div class="box box-success">
 <!--<div class="box-header"></div>-->
 <div class="box-body">
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr class="success">
   @foreach( $listing_cols as $col )
   <th>{{ $module->fields[$col]['label'] or ucfirst($col) }}</th>
   @endforeach
   @if($show_actions)
   <th>Actions</th>
   @endif
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

@la_access("Empleados", "create")
<div class="modal fade" id="AddModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Empleado</h4>
   </div>
   {!! Form::open(['action' => 'LA\EmpleadosController@store', 'id' => 'empleado-add-form']) !!}
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="box-body">
                    @la_form($module)
     
     {{--
     @la_input($module, 'apellido_paterno')
     @la_input($module, 'apellido_materno')
     @la_input($module, 'nombre')
     @la_input($module, 'empresa')
     @la_input($module, 'departamento')
     @la_input($module, 'puesto')
     @la_input($module, 'fecha_nacimiento')
     @la_input($module, 'direccion')
     @la_input($module, 'ciudad')
     @la_input($module, 'sexo')
     @la_input($module, 'curp')
     @la_input($module, 'rfc')
     @la_input($module, 'nss')
     @la_input($module, 'correo')
     @la_input($module, 'contrato_adicional')
     @la_input($module, 'infonavit')
     @la_input($module, 'banco')
     @la_input($module, 'cuenta')
     @la_input($module, 'tarjeta')
     @la_input($module, 'clave_interbancaria')
     @la_input($module, 'fecha_ingreso')
     @la_input($module, 'contrato')
     @la_input($module, 'renovacion_contrato')
     @la_input($module, 'reglamento_interno')
     @la_input($module, 'aviso_privacidad')
     @la_input($module, 'cyc')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_lunes')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_martes')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_miercoles')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_jueves')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_viernes')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_sabado')
     @la_input($module, 'horario_domingo')
     @la_input($module, 'renuncia')
     @la_input($module, 'finiquito')
     @la_input($module, 'convenio')
     @la_input($module, 'baja_imss')
     --}}
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    {!! Form::submit( 'Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']) !!}
   </div>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
@endla_access

@endsection

@push('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('la-assets/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css') }}"/>
@endpush

@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('la-assets/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
 $("#example1").DataTable({
  processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ url(config('laraadmin.adminRoute') . '/empleado_dt_ajax') }}",
  language: {
   lengthMenu: "_MENU_",
   search: "_INPUT_",
   searchPlaceholder: "Search"
  },
  @if($show_actions)
  columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [-1] }],
  @endif
 });
 $("#empleado-add-form").validate({
  
 });
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Podrias compartir el código que usas para hacer la perición.

Comment: Estos son los bloques de código que mas uso.